# Link Between AS3 FPS and Performance?

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, frame-rate

So I'm wondering if lowering FPS from my default (30) to around 20 would improve performance. Is there are link between the two because a computer running a 30fps program would have to update more often than one running at 20fps?  Or does it just matter that you maintain your default fps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [Elastic Racetrack](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/), it should be interesting.